# mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to select all records from the `users` table. This code works properly in local but it shows error in the server.

Here's the code:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

Error:

[image: error message from terminal SSH at my server]

Comment: uhm , maybe your mysql server just respond with local ...but not by IP (public or private)....pls check it with to telnet localhost 3306 from where is hosted your script python

Comment: check this - > https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-mysqld-server-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address/

Comment: hmm, i cant understand :(

Comment: sorry, it was too late for me ... what don't you understand?

Comment: no problem, I try to connect the database with PHP and work properly. but can't connect using python